# Blue card start date?

Tags: germany, resident-permit, blue-card

I had got a great job offer in germany and moved to Germany on national visa type D for work. It's a long term work visa for skilled workers. I entered Germany on October, 2020 on the above visa. Within next 3 months, I was issued EU blue card as on January, 2021. My question is when I calculate my 33 months duration to become eligible for applying for permanent residency, would it start from Oct, 2020 or January, 2021?

Comment: The first month that you worked. The months you paid into the pension system is what counts. Each partial month counts as a full month, so if you started working on the 20th of October, October is the first month.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. Your residence clock for the purpose of applying for a daueraufenthaltstitel with an EU blue card begins when you take up work in the country. This means from the date of the start of your employment contract.

According to the [Berlin service portal](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326556/en/):

> - Possession of an EU Blue Card No less than 33 months of employment and basic knowledge of the German language

Answer (score 0):

> My question is when I calculate my 33 months duration to become eligible for applying for permanent residency,...

The first month that you worked.

The months you paid into the pension system is what counts.

Each partial month counts as a full month, so if you started working on the 20th of October, October is the first month.